# Changing PHP session variable

Tags: php

I'm experiencing a strange PHP session issue. Can someone tell me if that's how session works?

To see the problem, load the following code into any php file, say test.php, and run it 2 times. NOTE, you have to run it two times, i.e. load the page and reload it.

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION["test"] = "Original////";
$test=$_SESSION["test"];
echo $_SESSION["test"];
$test="New////";
echo $_SESSION["test"];
?>
```

On my server, the first time I load this test page, I get

Original////Original////

and that is correct. But when I reload it, I get

Original////New////

which means the 5th line "$test="New////";" actually rewrite my $_SESSION["test"]. That doesn't make sense to me. Anyone knows what is happening? Or it's just happening on my server???

Comment: That indeed should not be happening. Is this the entire code? No references used anywhere? More code that changes the value later on?

Comment: Can't think of a reason that would be happening unless you have only given us a segment of the code...

Comment: Please make sure that register_globals isn't enabled on your server.

Comment: Tested that code on my machine, hit refresh I get Original////Original//// each time.

Comment: code is working as expected on my machine too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is enabled on your server. You'll need to disable the directive.

Comment: nice catch,, so long since i have seen a server with that on, you just don't think about it any more.

Comment: @Dagon Got caught out by it last year. Host had a "misconfiguration". Suffice to say, I tore my hair out for a while before I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not use `<?` as a starting tag of PHP, please use `<?php`. Secondly, this is an expected behavior if you have `register_globals` enabled. Look at this link:

http://www.theblog.ca/session-register-globals

It's title says:

> When register_globals is on, session variables overwrite global variables

And sample code is similar to yours:

```
<?php
session_start();
$canadaday = 'July 1st';
$_SESSION['canadaday'] = 'July 2nd';

print '<p>When is Canada Day?</p>';
print '<p><strong>' . $canadaday . '</strong></p>';
?>
```

With `register_globals`, result is `July 2nd`. HTH.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["test"] = "Original////";
$test=$_SESSION["test"];
echo $_SESSION["test"];
$test="New////";
echo $_SESSION["test"];
?>
```

I have tried your code in my environment its running perfectly.its always print Original////Original////
so its happening only on your server

Comment: -1, you don't have `register_globals` enabled that's why it "works for you".